# Interface Class and Object Class is compiling symbol errors

Tags: java, object, interface

I am a beginner here at JAVA and I am trying to program a Gratuity Calculator using both interface class and object class but it keeps on compiling with errors saying "cannot find symbol".I tried everything to fix it but it just keeps on stating symbol. Please help.

```
  public class GratuityCalculator extends JFrame
{
 /* declarations */

// color objects
   Color black = new Color(0, 0, 0);
   Color white = new Color(255, 255, 255);
   Color light_gray = new Color(192, 192, 192);

 // components
   JLabel billAmountJLabel;
   JTextField billAmountJTextField;

   JLabel gratuityAmountJLabel;
   JTextField gratuityAmountJTextField;

   JButton enterJButton;
   JButton clearJButton;
   JButton closeJButton;

  // variables
  double billAmount;
  double gratuityAmount;
  double firstNumber;
  final double GRATUITY_RATE = .15;


// objects
  CalculateDoubles calculateDoubles; // object class declaration

  public GratuityCalculator()
  {
        createUserInterface();
  }

  public void createUserInterface()
  {
    Container contentPane = getContentPane();
    contentPane.setBackground(Color.white);
    contentPane.setLayout(null);

    /* initialize components */

    billAmountJLabel = new JLabel();
    billAmountJLabel.setBounds(50, 50, 120, 20);
    billAmountJLabel.setFont(new Font("Default", Font.PLAIN, 12));
    billAmountJLabel.setText("Enter First Number:");
    billAmountJLabel.setForeground(black);
    billAmountJLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.LEFT);
    contentPane.add(billAmountJLabel);

    billAmountJTextField = new JTextField();
    billAmountJTextField.setBounds(225, 50, 50, 20);
    billAmountJTextField.setFont(new Font("Default", Font.PLAIN, 12));
    billAmountJTextField.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);
    billAmountJTextField.setForeground(black);
    billAmountJTextField.setBackground(white);
    billAmountJTextField.setEditable(true);
    contentPane.add(billAmountJTextField);

    gratuityAmountJLabel = new JLabel();
    gratuityAmountJLabel.setBounds(50, 80, 150, 20);
    gratuityAmountJLabel.setFont(new Font("Default", Font.PLAIN, 12));
    gratuityAmountJLabel.setText("Enter Second Number:");
    gratuityAmountJLabel.setForeground(black);
    gratuityAmountJLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.LEFT);
    contentPane.add(gratuityAmountJLabel);

    gratuityAmountJTextField = new JTextField();
    gratuityAmountJTextField.setBounds(225, 80, 50, 20);
    gratuityAmountJTextField.setFont(new Font("Default", Font.PLAIN, 12));
    gratuityAmountJTextField.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);
    gratuityAmountJTextField.setForeground(black);
    gratuityAmountJTextField.setBackground(white);
    gratuityAmountJTextField.setEditable(false);
    contentPane.add(gratuityAmountJTextField);

    enterJButton = new JButton();
    enterJButton.setBounds(20, 300, 100, 20);
    enterJButton.setFont(new Font("Default", Font.PLAIN, 12));
    enterJButton.setText("Enter");
    enterJButton.setForeground(black);
    enterJButton.setBackground(white);
    contentPane.add(enterJButton);
    enterJButton.addActionListener(

        new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
            {
                enterJButtonActionPerformed(event);
            }
        }
    );

    clearJButton = new JButton();
    clearJButton.setBounds(130, 300, 100, 20);
    clearJButton.setFont(new Font("Default", Font.PLAIN, 12));
    clearJButton.setText("Clear");
    clearJButton.setForeground(black);
    clearJButton.setBackground(white);
    contentPane.add(clearJButton);
    clearJButton.addActionListener(

        new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
            {
                clearJButtonActionPerformed(event);
            }
        }
    );

    closeJButton = new JButton();
    closeJButton.setBounds(240, 300, 100, 20);
    closeJButton.setFont(new Font("Default", Font.PLAIN, 12));
    closeJButton.setText("Close");
    closeJButton.setForeground(black);
    closeJButton.setBackground(white);
    contentPane.add(closeJButton);
    closeJButton.addActionListener(

        new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
            {
                closeJButtonActionPerformed(event);
            }
        }
    );

    setTitle("Gratuity Calculator");
    setSize(400, 400);
    setVisible(true);
}

// main method
public static void main(String[] args)
{
        GratuityCalculator application = new GratuityCalculator();
        application.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}

public void enterJButtonActionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
{
    getDoubleOne();
}

public void getDoubleOne()
{
    try
    {
        billAmount = Double.parseDouble(billAmountJTextField.getText());
        getGratuityAmount();
    }
    catch(NumberFormatException exception)
    {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,
            "Please enter bill amount!",
            "Number Format Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE );
            billAmountJTextField.setText("");
            billAmountJTextField.requestFocusInWindow();
    }
}

public void getGratuityAmount()
{
    /* initalize the object class */
    calculateDouble = new calculateDouble();
    calculateDoubles.setFirstValue(billAmount);
    displayGratuityAmount();

}

public void displayGratuityAmount()
{
    /* call object class method */
    gratuityAmountNumber = calculateDouble.getGratuityAmountNumber();

    gratuityAmountJTextField.setText("" + gratuityAmountNumber);
}

public void clearJButtonActionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
{
    billAmountJTextField.setText("");
    billAmountJTextField.requestFocusInWindow();
    gratuityAmountTextField.setText("");

}

public void closeJButtonActionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
{
    GratuityCalculator.this.dispose();
}

} 

class CalculateDoubles
{
/* object class variables */
double billAmount;
double gratuityAmount;
double firstNumber;
final double GRATUITY_RATE = .15;


/* first value is received by object class */
public CalculateDoubles(double billAmount)
{
    firstNumber = billAmount;
}

/* return method sends sum of values to interface class */
public double getGratuityAmount()
{
    return firstNumber * GRATUITY_RATE;
}
```

}

Comment: Where is `firstNumber` defined?

Answer (score 0):

Some errors...

Add firstNumber to class CalculateDoubles:

```
class CalculateDoubles  {/* object class non-constructor */

    /* object class variables */
    double billAmount;
    double gratuityAmount;
    double firstNumber;
    ...
```

Define GRATUITY_RATE:

```
double GRATUITY_RATE = 0.15;
```

I see some other errors, seems you did not posted all the class contents.

Comment: Thank you. I made the changes you suggested but it still stated the same errors. It can't seem to find the symbol for calculate.

Comment: You can edit the question and put all the code. That would work for better understanding.

Comment: I have edited the question and put the whole code in. I hope someone can figure out the problem. It shows six errors - all of which is 'cannot find symbol' Thank you!